# Audio Editing using Python

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, editing

Please I want to use python to edit an audio recording I did with my phone to enhance the sound and make it clearer.
Which library can I use for this purpose?

I don't know if I can use PyAudio entirely for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *librosa* in python.
It is a full library for audio preprocessing.
You can load audio with

```
librosa.load('path/to/audiofile')
```

and edit with *numpy*.
after that you can save it with *soundfile.save()* function.